# SVN Pathname not terminated by ':'

Tags: svn, merge, git-svn

The following command

```
svn log -g
```

executed on my repository returns a lot of log info but eventually dies with

```
svn: Pathname not terminated by ':'
```

The story here is that someone in the past had manually edited the merge info (because they were using a git-SVN bridge that borked things) but it appears that the mergeinfo was not fixed correctly.

Unfortunately, this is causing problems with my IDE as it is executing the command

```
svn log --xml --with-all-revprops -r HEAD:1 -v -l 101 -g
```

against the repository before doing a merge which is dying with the same error message.

How can we fix the repository to get rid of this nightmare?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually edit the mergeinfo on a directory or file with:

```
$ svn propedit svn:mergeinfo <directory>
```

That will open the mergeinfo in a text editor, by default vi. Edit it, save and quit. Then commit the change:

```
$ svn commit <directory>
```

Comment: What am I looking for? Because when I look at this I get a *very* short list of branches and merge info and they all look kosher to my naive eyes.

Comment: @SVNMustDie Maybe it's not the top-level mergeinfo. Sub-directories can have their own mergeinfo.

Comment: What am I looking for? How can narrow down the search to which sub-directory I should be looking at?

Comment: @SVNMustDie Try `svn ls -R | xargs -d '\n' -n 1 svn proplist | less`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find the broken `svn:mergeinfo` using this command:

```
svn pget svn:mergeinfo -R . | grep -v :
```

This will print the `svn:mergeinfo` lines missing a colon.

Valid `svn:mergeinfo` lines normally look like this:

```
trunk - /branches/feature1:8
```

where `trunk` is the path that has the `svn:mergeinfo` property, `/branches/feature1` is a path that was merged (in this example into `trunk`), and after the colon is a listing of revision numbers and ranges that were merged, for example `8,11-15,41,44`.

**UPDATE**

This article might be related: http://limedaley.com/post/changing-paths-while-migrating-subversion-repositories

In that example the `svn:mergeinfo` content was incorrectly rewritten, but it seems to me that would result in a completely broken repository, which is different from your case, so I don't know....

Maybe a possible solution is to delete all the `svn:mergeinfo` properties, see if that fixes your problem, and then add them back later, correctly. You can delete the property like this:

```
svn propdel svn:mergeinfo -R .
```

Comment: All lines match the regular expression `:` so no lines are returned by `svn pget svn:merge info -R . | grep -v :`.

Comment: Then I don't where the `Pathname not terminated by ':'` comes from... :-/ Btw in your comment you wrote `svn:merge info` with a space between `svn:merge` and `info` but I guess you ran the command without a space right?

Comment: I don't get where it's coming from either. :-( Yes, I did type it as `mergeinfo` and not `merge info`, that was just a stupid auto-correct here.